# How to set SolverId when setting verbosity in IK solver options in Drake toolbox?

Tags: robotics, drake

```
 drake::solvers::SolverOptions options;
    options.SetOption(drake::solvers::**?**, "verbose", {0, 1});   //{0,1} for verbose, {0,0} for no verbosity
    const auto result = Solve(ik.prog(), {}, options);
    const auto q_sol = result.GetSolution(ik.q());
```

What do I set the  SolverId to for solving the Inverse Kinematics nlp problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Set the option for the specific solver you use. You can know which solver is invoked by checking the `result`

   ```cc
   std::cout << result.get_solver_id().name() << "\n";
   ```

   if it prints "IPOPT", then you can do `options.SetOption(drake::solvers::IpoptSolver::id(), ...)`.
2. Another (and better) solution is to set the common solver options

   ```cc
   options.SetOption(CommonSolverOption::kPrintToConsole, 1);
   ```

   which will print the output information to the console for any solver that supports console printing. You can also do `options.SetOption(CommonSolverOption::kPrintFileName, "output.txt")` which will print the output to `output.txt` file.

Comment: `drake::solvers::SolverOptions options;
    options.SetOption(drake::solvers::CommonSolverOption::kPrintToConsole, 1);
    const auto result = Solve(ik.prog(), {}, options);` Does not display anything in the console. Am I missing something? My [IK Formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69590113/how-to-set-up-ik-trajectory-optimization-in-drake-toolbox)

Comment: ```std::cout << result.get_solver_id().name() << "\n";``` gives me: `SNOPT/fortran` in the terminal.

Comment: Since you are using SNOPT, which doesn't support print to console. You should set `kPrintToFile` option.